# Is there a sass/css selector for "is descendant or has class"?

Tags: css, sass

I want to select an element if it has the class `.eventContainer` and has a parent with class `.todo`, or if it has the classes `.grid` and `.todo`:

```
.todo .eventContainer,
.grid.todo
    background-color: gray
```

Is there a way to do this with nesting to avoid specifying the `.todo` class twice?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, works. I will accept it if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in the comments, you can use ampersand operator (see [official documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)) to insert parent selector in a nested rule, something like this:

```
.todo
  & .eventContainer,
  &.grid
    background-color: gray
```

This will compile into:

```
.todo .eventContainer,
.todo.grid {
  background-color: gray;
}
```